# How to approach this question: For arbitrary subspaces of $U , V ,W$ of a finite dimensional vector space, which of the following hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

This question was asked in my assignment of linear algebra and I am not able to make any significant progress on it:

> Question: For arbitrary subspaces $U, V,W$ of a finite dimensional vector space, which of the following hold:

(a) $U \cap (V+W) \subset U \cap V + U \cap W$

(b)$ U \cap V + U \cap W \subset U \cap (V+W) $

(c) $ (U \cap V )+W \subset (U +W) \cap (V+W)$

(d) $(U +W) \cap (V+W)  \subset (U \cap V )+W $

Can you please give hints on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Please first edit your post to share your thoughts and attempts, even if partial.[ Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).